# forming three-digit integers

Tags: combinatorics

Can anyone help me on this? This is probably a simple problem, but I don't know how to do it. I think that I may be lack of the knowledge in this area. To solve similar problems, what materials should I learn? Which category does this problem belongs to?

Problem: How many different, positive three-digit integers can be formed using any three of the following five digits: 1, 2, 2, 3, and 3?

Comment: 18. There are 4 sets aab each giving 3 numbers and a set abc giving 6 numbers.

Comment: Thank you! What materials should I learn to solve similar problems?

Comment: You can also first calculate number of the different integers if 1,2,3 can be placed at any digit. There are $3^3=27$ different integers. Then substract the cases  with the digits $\{1,1,3\}$, $\{1,1,2\}$  and the cases with equal digits: $27-3-3-3=18$

Answer (score 1):

Let's replace the digits with letters:

- $1\rightarrow{X}$
- $2\rightarrow{Y}$
- $3\rightarrow{Z}$

Now, simply add up the following:

- The number of permutations of $[\color\red{X},\color\green{Y},\color\green {Y}]$ is $\frac{3!}{\color\red1!\color\green2!               }=3$
- The number of permutations of $[\color\red{X},\color\green{Y},\color\orange{Z}]$ is $\frac{3!}{\color\red1!\color\green1!\color\orange1!}=6$
- The number of permutations of $[\color\red{X},\color\green{Z},\color\green {Z}]$ is $\frac{3!}{\color\red1!\color\green2!               }=3$
- The number of permutations of $[\color\red{Y},\color\red  {Y},\color\green {Z}]$ is $\frac{3!}{\color\red2!\color\green1!               }=3$
- The number of permutations of $[\color\red{Y},\color\green{Z},\color\green {Z}]$ is $\frac{3!}{\color\red1!\color\green2!               }=3$

Hence the total number of permutations is $3+6+3+3+3=18$.

---

I've replaced the digits with letters in order to make the answer more readable.

Answer (score 1):

(**Another approach** -- just for fun!)

Either you have a repeat -- two $2$s or two $3$s -- or all numbers are distinct.

The number of combos with two $2$s is the same as the number with two $3$s; you match them up by listing the former, and switching $2$ and $3$ to get a list of the latter.

(E.g., $221$ matches with $331$, or $232$ matches with $323$.)

- If all three digits are different, then you have the arrangements of $1, 2, 3$ in $3! = 6$ ways.

For the other two cases, let's count out what happens if there are two $2$s, then two $3$s:

- The non-$2$ is in one of *three* places, and can be one of *two* choices ($1$ or $3$); so there are $6$ ways.
- Again, two $3$s will have the same count by our matching; so, another $6$ ways.

Summarizing: $6+6+6 = 18$ ways. **QED**.

Answer (score 1):

$123$ and permutations $\to6$

$122$ and permutations $\to3$

$133$ and permutations $\to3$

$223$ and permutations $\to3$

$233$ and permutations $\to3$